# Check File size powershell ssh

Tags: powershell, ssh

I use this script for check file size. How can I make to verify each computers ip's in ip.txt and the result print in results.txt ?

Thank you!

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path C:\Users\user\Desktop\Check_File.txt -append

$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\ip.txt

foreach($Computer in $Computers){

    $User = "admin"
    $Password = "paSSw"
    $Command = "dir C:\Proset\SRM\abc.ddc && hostname"

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command | Select -Expand Output > result.txt
}
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by "verify" - can you explain what you want to validate/ensure here?

Comment: verify size of "abc.ddc" for each computer (ip computers is in ip.txt) and the result print in result.txt ; script work's well if i put manually -ComputerName IP

Comment: Then you need to check the input file I guess. Does it have empty lines maybe? Try with `$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\ip.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }` to skip empty or whitespace only lines

Comment: I also think you should change `> result.txt` to `| Add-Content -Path result.txt`